# Gradient and rounded corners work in IE9, but not IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, rounded-corners, css

Could someone explain to me why this looks just fine in IE9 (as well as Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera), but in IE10 the rounded corners disappear?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
padding: 0px 20px;
background: #698ac6;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #96b3eb 0%, #698ac6 40%, #6c8ecc 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#96b3eb), color-stop(40%,#698ac6), color-stop(100%,#6c8ecc));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #96b3eb 0%,#698ac6 40%,#6c8ecc 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #96b3eb 0%,#698ac6 40%,#6c8ecc 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #96b3eb 0%,#698ac6 40%,#6c8ecc 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #96b3eb 0%,#698ac6 40%,#6c8ecc 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#96b3eb', endColorstr='#6c8ecc',GradientType=0 );
width: auto;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 44px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 36px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>DASHBOARD</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried deleting, moving, or nesting various elements, but without effect. It seems like if it works in IE9, it shouldn't have a problem with 10. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you *sure* you've got your IE versions the right way round? There is a very well-known issue in IE9 when combining `border-radius` with `filter` gradients; this doesn't work and you don't get the rounded corners. IE10 doesn't have this bug, and should be fine. Therefore you code should be broken as described in IE9, not IE10.

Comment: by the way, you shouldn't need the SVG background gradient and the `filter` style together; you've covered all the bases already without it. You should be able to drop either one or the other (depending on whether you need to support IE8).

Comment: works for me in ie10 compat view http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/VUcbX/

Comment: I don't see anything these that shouldn't work in IE10. Can you post a demo so that we can debug? Also, you don't need the -ms- prefix for IE as IE10 directly added gradients without prefix. The -ms- prefix was only briefly used in a platform preview.

Comment: @Spudley, yes I'm *absolutely sure* I've got the IE versions the right way round. That's the whole reason for the post. If it worked in IE10, but not 9 I would have assumed it was just a compatibility issue with the older version, but the fact that I can see it in IE9 correctly, but not 10 is what's puzzling me.

Comment: @albert, jsfiddle is a nifty tool. Thanks for that. When I view the results from jsfiddle in IE10, it looks correct, but it still won't display correctly when I try to view that information on its own.

Comment: @dstorey, Everything I've got right now is in the HTML listed in the question. The gradient came from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @popvoid as the code you posted works fine in IE10 when using something like jsfiddle, there is something outside of that code with your setup that is causing it not to work. It is going to be impossible for us to debug without being able to run the code as you see it. The only only thing I can think of is that you are in compatibility mode some how. Can you open the dev tools and make sure it is set to IE10 for both modes?

Comment: @dstorey Yipes! That did the trick. Once I turned off compatibility mode it was fine in IE10. How it got turned on in the first place, I don't know. Since it was already working in IE9, I guess compatibility mode isn't all it's cracked up to be. Thanks!

Comment: so....how do we close this or give @dstorey credit?

Comment: @albert I’ll add an answer regarding compat mode.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in your code is correct for both border-radius and gradients for IE10. IE includes a compatibility mode that can emulate standards support in older versions of the browser. In this case, it looks like this has been enabled in your copy of IE10. You can check the compatibility and document mode that IE is using by opening the developer tools (F12) and checking both in the top toolbar. Switching to IE10 and standards mode should solve the issue.

Comment: I used it in IE 10 and it didn't work properly even though can I use said that gradients should work in IE 10.